# Android Studio Javadoc, how to include overview.html?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin, javadoc

I would like to incorporate my overview.html file into the generated javadocs.  With "ordinary" java I just added an overview.html file next to the .java files in the package source directory and it worked.

In the Android Studio Javadoc dialogue I added this to the *Other command line arguments* field:

*-overview overview.html*

But it never finds this file.  I always get:
*javadoc: error - Error while reading file overview.html*
The only thing that works is if I hard code the full path.  (*-overview c:....\overview.html*) but that seems awkward.

I've tried moving overview.html around, to no avail.

The overview.html file itself it simple, like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>[S. Yawn, Bureaucratosis] Gas mine treaty blah blah bl-blah </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I suspect one possibility is to alter the build.gradle file to manually copy the overview file over to the build directory that Android uses as the source directory when constructing the javadocs.  But I admit I haven't dug into that idea yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with Gradle. In your app/build.gradle you have to add a javadoc task:

```
task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    destinationDir = file("../javadoc/")
    failOnError false
}
```

To automatically add your overview.html as index, extend the script this way:

```
task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    destinationDir = file("../javadoc/")
    failOnError false
    options.overview = "src/main/javadoc/overview.html"
}
```

You can then add the javadoc in a jar and publish it as an archive:

```
task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives javadocJar
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  The project was ended shortly thereafter and I went off to do non-Android work.  But I'm back now and your solution works great!